# Поиск в таблице MySQL по наименованию

Tags: c#, mysql

Помогите, пожалуйста, с поиском в бд mysql, есть хранимая процедура, которая ищет в таблице Street запись по полю:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `FiendAddres` (ch bool, str varchar(150)) 
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
if ch = 1 then
    SELECT postal_code, street_name FROM Street
    WHERE street_name like ('%' + RTRIM(str) + '%');
else
    SELECT postal_code, street_name FROM Street;
END if;
END

В Visual SStudio на форму накидал DataGrid, TextBox и Button
Создал метод GetData()(строку подключения к бд прописал в app.config), на Button повесил событие button1_Click:
       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string fr1 = textBox1.Text;
            string fr2 = textBox2.Text;
            bool ch = checkBox1.Checked;
            fr1.ToLower();
            fr2.ToLower();
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection();
            ConnectionStringSettings conString;
            conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQLConStr"];
             dataGridView1.DataSource = GetData(ch, /*fr1,*/ fr2);
        }
        DataTable GetData(bool ch,string fr2)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            ConnectionStringSettings conString;
            conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQLConStr"];

            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conString.
                                             ConnectionString))
            {
                MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand("FiendAddres", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
               MySqlParameter p = new MySqlParameter();
                p = new MySqlParameter();
                p.ParameterName = "str";
                p.DbType = DbType.String;
                p.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar;
                p.Size = 150;
                p.IsNullable = true;
                p.Value = fr2;
                com.Parameters.Add(p);

                p = new MySqlParameter();
                p.ParameterName = "ch";
                p.DbType = DbType.Boolean;
                p.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Bit;
                p.Size = 1;
                p.IsNullable = true;
                p.Value = ch;
                com.Parameters.Add(p);
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    using (MySqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (dr.HasRows)
                        {
                            dt.Load(dr);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }
    }
```

Ввожу в `TextBox` искомое наименование, результат 0-ой, не могу понять в чем проблемма

Comment: Wireshark в помощь. Поможет отловить что отсылается бызе и что приходит взамен.

Comment: Есть у Вас мануал как настроить Wireshark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Открываем программу, выбираем нужный сетевой интерфейс с помощью `Ctrl+I`.
- Запускаем режим `capture` трафика через `Ctrl+E`.
- Запускаете свой программу и делаете тот самый запрос, который вас интересует.
- Выключаете режим `capture` через `Ctrl+E` опять же.
- Затем смотрим на пойманные пакеты.
- В поле `Filter` вводите `mysql` и нажимаем либо `Enter` либо сбоку кнопку `Apply`, чтобы отфильтровать лишние пакеты. По адресам догадываемся кто кому данный пакет шлет (т.е. `в базу` или `ответ от базы`). Затем выбираем пакет в верхнем окне, а в нижнем окне раскрываем нижний плюс. Дальше интуитивно, так как черным по белому написано конкретно то, что в присутствует трафике.

P.S.[Файл для тренировки](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=mysql_complete.pcap).

P.P.S. В поле `Filter` можно ввести `mysql` и потом начать через `capture` через `Ctrl+E`. Разницы в принципе никакой нет, просто отфильтрованный трафик будет показываться с самого начала.